# Raster reprojection from EPGS:4269 to EPSG:4326

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, gdal, dem

I downloaded dem rasters for USA and they use EPSG 4269 CRS. Now, I want to sample raster values (elevation) at some points that use EPGS:4326 CRS.
Do I need to reproject rasters to 4326 before sampling values?

Comment: Well, have you tried sampling before reprojecting? And why reproject the raster, which is rather computational expensive, while you could reproject the points?

Comment: Yeah, I could eventually reproject points, it is better solution. I was just curious about EPSG:4269 -> EPSG:4326 reprojection.

Comment: Technically, it's not reprojection, but NADCON (NAD conversion) to translate between WGS84 and NAD83, and they're mostly very close over CONUS, but yes conversion is necessary.

Comment: What's the resolution of the raster? NAD83 (4269) and WGS84 (4326) at this point are buckets used for a bunch of re-adjustments over the last 30-odd years. The most recent NAD83 (2011) and WGS84 (G1762) are about a meter off in lower 48 states.

Comment: @Vince NADCON is just for converting between NAD realizations/re-adjustments. No conversion to WGS84 is available in it. There are some transformations between specific NAD83 realizations and specific ITRF realizations. The last few WGS84 realizations are stated to be equivalent with a particular ITRF so that's one way to do it.